# What algorithm to use to check if one set overlaps to another?

Tags: c#, algorithm, set, hashset, sortedset

I have many sets of integers. I need to check if one overlaps (at least one same element exists in both sets) to another. What is the best way to do it. I compared two ways:

```
HashSet<int> hs1, hs2;
hs1.Overlaps(hs2);
```

and

```
SortedSet<int> ss1, ss2;
ss1.Overlaps(ss2);
```

HashSet is beter because in both cases overlaps gets enumerable, and do scan in enumerable and lookup in set.

But I feel that beter algorithm exists to check overlaping in sorted sets.

**Does anyone know algorithm which allows to quick check overlaping using the fact that both sets is sorted?**

**UPD1**
The size of each set is about 100-1000 well distributed integers.

Comment: If your sequences are sorted you can perform a merge. That's probably faster than building a hash table.

Comment: @usr, the cost of building sets is out of scope. But anyway building a hash table usually faster than sorting

Comment: Are you concerned with absolute throughput or with asymptotic complexity?

Comment: @usr, my goal is to increase performance, I want to achieve high average throughput on real data.

Comment: Can you perform any kind of precomputation such as sorting, building hash tables or other things? Are the integers from a small range (such as [1, 10000])? In that case you could build a bitmap and intersect using binary and.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do better than `O(min(size of the first set, size of the second set))`, because you cannot tell if two sets intersect without looking through all elements of at least one of them in the worst case.

Comment: That is true but you can achieve better absolute throughput.

Comment: @usr It requires some additional information about the sets, which is not present in the question.

Comment: If we dealing with sorted sets, probably we can use this fact and not need to look through all elements. This is exactly what the my question about.

Answer (score 0):

This depends quite a lot on the size of the problem (may be a few hundred to a few trillion entries per set) and the way the input is presented (files ? fits into memory ? on multiple machines).

In general, with pure comparisons, we can't find all overlapping sets better than O(n * log(n)) where 'n' is the total number of elements since duplicate detection (proven to be Omega(n * log (n)) can be reduced to this problem. There are a few other heuristics that can be used depending on the size of the problem and data sets if we use this fact: two sets can overlap only if the end-points overlap, i.e., suppose A = {a1, ..., aN} and B = {b1, ..., bN}. A and B can't overlap if (aN < b1) || (bN < a1). This can be used to eliminate a number of comparisons. But in the worst case all ranges could overlap and we may have to look at all sets bringing the worst case to the above. Also, the SortedSet::Overlaps function will likely do the above comparison internally.

With extra memory (using a hash / map), you can do better. Consider the following analogy: Suppose you plot the 'range' of the sets on a number line by plotting the smallest and largest elements and the numbers in between. All you need to know is to check if the same point has been plotted twice. Building from that, here's a possible way: (I don't know the C# equivalent for this algo)

1. Create a hashmap M from int -> {set name}. So if an element '5' belongs to set '3', we say M[5] --> {3}.
2. Loop through all elements in all sets.
3. If a map already exists, you have an overlap between the current set (say 17) being looped and the set value present in the map. Also add the new set to the RHS. So for the element above, we'll see M[5] --> {3, 17}

The time complexity of the above is O(n * (cost of insertion into set)) . (It's actually n * (cost of hash lookup) * (cost of insertion into set) but we can assume for the sake of this problem that a hash has constant lookup / insertion time)

Cost of insertion into set is O(log(size of set)). The size of the set could be 'n' in the worst case as all sets may be overlapping with each other. But if many sets are not likely to overlap we could assume constant time for it making the time complexity into O(n).

Note that the above solution does not use the fact that the sets are themselves sorted since we are not making use of ordering.

Comment: So why the -1 ? Comments would be useful.

Comment: @useruser1952500, thanks for your answer. I add more details about sets properties. I also will try to make algorithm with reduced number of comprations, and add results here.